# SQL JSON HELP | Selecting ALL records with a certain JSON value

Tags: sql, json

I am trying to get all records that contain `WEAPON_COMBATPISTOL` in the column `inventory` within my **users table**.
It is based on JSON. I am lost I have tried JSON_EXTRACT & JSON_CONTAINS.

JSON DATA:

```
[{"slot":1,"count":450,"name":"money"},
{"slot":2,"count":54,"name":"ammo-9"},
{"metadata":{"serial":"643280CXJ213639","durability":97.91999999999998,"registered":"Barry McCeiner","components":[],"ammo":11},"slot":3,"count":1,"name":"WEAPON_COMBATPISTOL"},
{"slot":4,"count":8,"name":"burger"},
{"slot":5,"count":8,"name":"icetea"},
{"slot":6,"count":7,"name":"stone"},
{"slot":10,"count":6,"name":"lockpick"}]
```

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(inventory, 'WEAPON_COMBATPISTOL', '$.name');
```

I also want to remove just the `WEAPON_COMBATPISTOL` from the JSON data. If that is possible.

Comment: why the Lua tag?

Comment: It was because I am doing this for FiveM (Lua Based) Programming. Removed.

Comment: You cant use JSON_CONTAINS because you have a list of different possible paths. Could this be a duplicate of [How to search nested JSON in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714984/how-to-search-nested-json-in-mysql)?